# Waiting for an async function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying out some async code to avoid locking up the UI while my program runs a time-consuming function (using Visual Studio 2022).

Here's what I've got so far - the program is running through pdf filename entries from a datagrid and performing the function on the filenames it finds:

```
Async Sub process_files()

    For Each myrow In DGV_inputfiles.Rows

        inputPDF = myrow.cells("col_filenamefull").value
        outputPDF = myrow.cells("col_outname").value

        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           time_consuming_function(inputPDF, outputPDF)
                       End Sub)
    Next

End Sub
```

At the moment, the program is not waiting for the 'time_consuming_function' to finish, so it's getting to the end of the sub before some of the output files are generated - so it appears to the user that it has finished when it's actually still working.

I believe the solution is something to do with returning a value from the function and waiting for it, but I can't quite see how it works - could anyone help please?

Comment: that make no sense, why doing it asynchron, when you want to wait for it to finish, which is synchron

Comment: I'm doing it asynch to avoid locking the UI. I have no need to run several tasks at once or anything like that, all I want is for it to wait until the function is finished telling the user it has finished.

Comment: sorry that last comment should have been: wait until the function is finished BEFORE telling the user it has finished.

Comment: no you would rewrite your function and make thread secure call to the ui for the confirmation

Comment: Not sure what you mean - sounds logical, but how would this look?

Comment: Just to clarify - the 'time_consuming_function' involves creating files - ie it's disk (I/O) based, not CPU-based. From what I've read, that's the difficulty.

Comment: If you're using Winforms, your best option is still the `BackgroundWorker` control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in time_consuming_function(...) you can send some infos to UI using invoke like this (assuming textbox1 exists in UI form):

```
sub time_consuming_function(...)
.... your stuff....
Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() textbox1.Text = "running...")
....
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work. From what I've read while researching this though, I may be better off using a Backgroundworker for functions with disk ops (like this one) and using RunWorkerCompleted. However, your solution will be useful for non-disk op stuff for sure - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `Await` is that it returns control to the UI until the expression or call that is `Await`ed completes.  It seems to be suited reasonably well to your workflow, you just need to make changes to `process_files` to be more user-friendly.

For example, you could have something in the UI update with the file that is currently being processed, and change it at the line before `Task.Run`.

e.g.

```vb
'(Inside the loop body)
CurrentOperation = $"Processing {inputPdf} into {outputPdf}..."
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(CurrentOperation)))
Await Task.Run(...)
```

You could disable UI controls before the `For` loop and re-enable them when it finishes.

The benefit of `Await` is that these changes will be easy, and the logical flow of the routine will be easy to follow.

Be aware that any `Await` presents an option for re-entrant code as the user may interact with the UI (this is true even for cases where everything is running on one thread as with async internet or I/O operations).

If you haven't done so already, I would recommend to read everything Stephen Cleary has written about asynchronous operations in .NET.

Comment: Stephen's blog is a very good recommend, thanks. I'm actually learning something, instead of just trying to copy/paste code from Google results! Some things you need to spend some time on and understand properly, but I so rarely get the time....